# PHP: illegal session id

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Session hijacking or attack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463175/session-hijacking-or-attack)

Lately I am receiving following error on my site

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,'
```

This error occurs on this line `session_start()` does anybody have idea why its happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#82957